# Getting lowest available field name with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form a where fields are named like  `data[Field][0][value], data[Field][1][value]`, et cetera, where the integer increments but the rest stays the same. Is there a way of finding out the lowest available integer value with jQuery?

My form uses JS to dynamically add and remove fields (some of which are created by the PHP backend on page load), so I need the lowest integer so as to create fields without conflicts.

Right now on page load, I set `field_count` to `$( "input[name$='[value]'" ).length;` and then increment it as I create my inputs. This prevents any namespace collisions, however it doesn't take removed inputs into consideration: I'd like to be able to re-use the names of removed fields.

Comment: What functionality are you trying to achieve? Using field names for logic is bad practice.

Comment: I have a form with fields which are dynamically added and removed by the user with Javascript. I need the lowest available integer so I can create new fields without conflicts.

Comment: If you using JavaScript to create the fields dynamically then you can track the elements created.

Comment: @sbjumani Not all fields are created with JS. Some are created in PHP. My bad, should have made that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If you can address `data[Field][0] ... data[Field][n]`, then I would say `data[Field]` is an `Array` and `data[Field].length` returns the current length of that `Array`. In that case the last value would then be in `data[Field][data[Field].length-1]` and the next available integer (index) would be `data[Field].length`.</strike>

Just for fun and to demonstrate an alternative: if you ditch the 'naming scheme' and use a data-attribute to keep track of the input fields, something like `<input type="text" data-idx="1">` you could use a method to dynamically determine the lowest slot available:

```
function getFreeSlot(inputFields) {
  var freeslots = []
     ,idxs      = inputFields.map(
                     function (i, el) { return +$(el).attr('data-idx');}
                   ).toArray()
  idxs.every( function (v,i) {
                void( v-(i ? 1 : 0) !== this[(i>0 ? i-1 : 0)]
                      && freeslots.push(this[(i>0 ? i-1 : 0)]+1) );
                return v; }, idxs );
  return freeslots.length ? freeslots[0] : idxs.length+1;
}
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/nLh2d33e/)

Comment: This assumes that elements are never removed. Not a reliable solution in my opinion.

Comment: If you remove an element from an `Array` (say, using `[array]splice`) or add an element to it (say using `[array].push`), its indexes and length are adjusted accordingly. My answer is not a *solution*, but a suggestion based on the up to now not contradicted assumption that `data[Field]` is, indeed, an `Array`.

Comment: data[Field] is a naming scheme generated by my PHP framework. Right now I'm creating fields with an incrementing `field_count` var, however if someone is indecisive and adds and removes a lot of variables the field_count goes outside of range pretty fast because `field_count` doesn't take removed vars into consideration.

Comment: @schnauss: adjusted the answer based on your comment and created an exemplary script.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your description is of the `name` attribute of the dynamically created/destroyed fields on the page (in other words, `<input name="Data[Field][0][value]">`):

```
var $lastField = $('[name^=Data\\[Field\\]\\[][name$=\\]\\[value\\]]').last();
var lastField = $lastField[0];
```

This should get the last element in the DOM with a name matching the regex `Data[Field][.*][value]`. If you want to ensure that the middle bit is a number, you need to get a little more involved:

```
var $lastField = $('[name^=Data\\[Field\\]\\[').filter(function(idx, element) {
    return /Data\[Field\]\[[0-9]+?\]\[value\]/.test($(this).attr('name'));
}).last();
var lastField = $lastField[0];
```

Comment: `$lastField` vs. `lastField` is simply a matter of preference, whether you want to work with a jQuery object or a DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Can you keep a list of the removed elements and then just pop one of those of the list to use when you need to create a new one (and if the list is empty, just increment your field_count as you are doing now).

Comment: That's turned out to be the simplest way to handle this: Before deleting an input, I get the integer with `deleted_fields.push($(this).closest('.input-group').find('input').attr("name").replace(/\D/g,''));` and then before creating a new one I check if `deleted_fields` has anything, if so I use the first ID and then pop it, otherwise I go with `field_count` and increment as usual.